# How can I filter and toggle polygons in Folium based on their 'VPN' value and name using groupedlayercontrol plugin?

Tags: python, leaflet, maps, folium

I'm trying to make a map in Folium of a group of polygons, these polygons have a feature called 'VPN' that can be either positive or negative, I would like to add a filter that turn off and on the polygons based on their VPN Value but also using their name

I tried adding the polygons to 3 different feature groups called positive group (VPN positive), negative group (VPN Negative) and polygons group (all of the polygons) so when using folium's groupedlayercontrol plugin I could easily turn off and on the polygons based on their group, but it turns out that the same polygon can't belong to two different feature groups so I resorted to duplicate the polygon but it is not the desired output, is there a way to do this? I would appreciate the feedback! here's my code:

```
m = folium.Map(location=[7.245361, -73.692524], zoom_start=10)

polygons = [{'name': 'Polygon 1', 'vpn': 'positive', 'coordinates': [(-73.692524, 7.113611), (-73.700712, 7.118302), (-73.691428, 7.13561), (-73.683846, 7.130675), (-73.692524, 7.113611)]},{'name': 'Polygon 2', 'vpn': 'negative', 'coordinates': [(-73.70558, 7.245361), (-73.71528, 7.250042), (-73.715232, 7.308858), (-73.68565, 7.308833), (-73.70558, 7.245361)]},]

positive_group = folium.FeatureGroup(name='Positive VPN')negative_group = folium.FeatureGroup(name='Negative VPN')polygons_group = folium.FeatureGroup(name='Polygons')

for polygon in polygons:coordinates = polygon['coordinates']feature = folium.GeoJson({'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [coordinates]},name=polygon['name'], style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor': 'green' if polygon['vpn'] == 'positive' else 'red'})

feature_2 = folium.GeoJson({'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [coordinates]},name=polygon['name'], style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor': 'green' if polygon['vpn'] == 'positive' else 'red'})

polygons_group.add_child(feature_2)

if polygon['vpn'] == 'positive':
    positive_group.add_child(feature)
else:
    negative_group.add_child(feature)

polygons_group.add_to(m)positive_group.add_to(m)negative_group.add_to(m)

grouped_layers = {'VPN': [positive_group, negative_group],'Polygons': [polygons_group],}

grouped_layer_control = GroupedLayerControl(grouped_layers, exclusive_groups=False)m.add_child(grouped_layer_control)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6I00.png)